# Infinite cycle in the parent process does not update the screen after using fork()

Tags: c, unix, fork, ncurses

I need to write UNIX appplication that creates 2 processes using fork(), both of these processes prints current time in different positions on the screen. Parent process must stop its work after the child process is over. I've written this code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct Point2
{
    int X;
    int Y;
};

int kbhit()
{
    //getch() implementation
}

void printTime(const struct Point2 pt, const char* st)
{
    char buf[255];
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    sprintf(buf, "%s: %02d:%02d:%02d", st, timeinfo->tm_hour,
            timeinfo->tm_min, timeinfo->tm_sec);
    mvaddstr(pt.Y, pt.X, buf);
    refresh();
}

void childp(pid_t pid, const struct Point2 pt)
{
    while(kbhit() != 27)
    {
        printTime(pt, "CHLD");
        usleep(1000);
    }
}

void parentp(pid_t pid, const struct Point2 pt)
{
    struct Point2 newp = {pt.X, pt.Y + 1};
    while(1)
    {
        int stat;
        waitpid(pid, &stat, WNOHANG);
        if(WIFEXITED(stat) != 0)
            break;

        printTime(newp, "PARN");
            usleep(1000);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("unable to load XY position for clock.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    initscr();
    refresh(); // <-- this refresh

    struct Point2 opt;
    opt.X = atoi(argv[1]);
    opt.Y = atoi(argv[2]);

    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    switch(pid)
    {
        case -1:
            printw("Error");
            _exit(0);
        case 0:
            childp(pid, opt);
            break;
        default:
        parentp(pid, opt);
            break;

    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Once the program is started, it outputs once "CHLD" and "PARN" time, and then correctly updates "CHLD" time from the child proccess, but the output from the parent process does not change. Moreover, if I comment the `refresh()` call in main() "PARN" time string does not show up at all. So my question is: why the parent process does not updates the screen?

upd. I have deleted almost all code in parent function's cycle, now it looks like:

```
void parentp(pid_t pid, const struct Point2 pt)
{
    struct Point2 newp = {pt.X, pt.Y + 1};
    while(1)
    {
        printTime(newp, "PARN");
    }
}
```

but it still not working

Comment: waitpid(pid, &stat, WNOHANG); This causes the parent process to wait if until there are no children, so the only reason it prints once is because it beats your child thread to the print statement and then when it loops, the child thread is running at that point.

Comment: @Magn3s1um well, and what do I have to do to satisfy the problem statement?

Comment: If you want them both to print the time whenever, don't have the parent wait at all.  Then it will just keep printing the parent's time.  Otherwise, you'll just have to send a signal from the child to the parent every time you want the parent to print the time.

Comment: @Magn3s1um the one of statements was "to shut down processes properly, do not kill or terminate them" Can you give an example for my case?

Comment: If you can't kill or terminate them from the parent, then the child processes will have to return normally.  You can't do that in an infinite while loop (unless there's a return statement in the while loop), so unless your child method's while loop terminates after a period of time, then you'll have to create a condition that isn't always true (looks like the child will terminate normally in your program).

Comment: okay then "shut down properly" means just "the function should return something?"

Comment: No, shutdown means that you get rid of "zombie children."  You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process

Comment: I have removed waitpid() in parent function, but it still not working (see updated post) any ideas why?

Comment: Just have it print the times on new lines, and print it like Parent: time /n Child time:   I bet you it has something to do with your PrintTime function and where you're trying to print to the screen, and you'll be able to tell by doing it this way.  If you still have the problem, it means it has something to do with your processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`waitpid(pid, &stat, WNOHANG);` worked correctly. I don't know why, but the problem was in `mvaddstr();` I changed it to printw() and voila, it worked! Maybe that's happening because `mvaddstr();` does not updates the whole screen. Another way is to draw PARN and CHLD time before calling fork(), but I think this is neither simple nor elegant solution. Used `printw().`